# Navbar not filling full screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I implemented a basic navbar using Bootstrap and here is the look of it:

[image]

As you can see, the bar does not fully covered the entire width with some empty margin space left. I changed `container` class to `container-fluid` and it just expands the navbar longer but still doesn't fit the entire screen.

Here is the code:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark ">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown
            </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>

      </ul>

    </div>
  </nav>

</div>
```

I also tried setting `.container` to `width:100%`.

Is this supposed to be like this?

How do I fix this?

Comment: Add a sample CSS code here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either you need to remove `.container-fluid` or add to it `.p-0` as `.container-fluid` is adding additional padding to the div. Please try the below snippet.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark ">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>

    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I remove `container-fluid` and it fills the screen now. Why does this work?

Comment: if you inspect `container-fluid` class, it adds `padding-right: 15px;padding-left: 15px;` which is why you need to remove it to get 100% screen width.

Comment: But in a youtube tutorial, I've seen them using container or container-fluid. When should one use it?

Comment: both classes can be used anywhere, but you need to keep in mind that, both these classes have `paddings`, so elements like navbar which needs to go `100%` should not ideally be used inside a `container`.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to remove .container-fluid class. because it take padding-right: 15px; and padding-left: 15px;

Answer (score 0):

You can either remove the `container-fluid` class or modify your existing `container-fluid` class in CSS as such:

```css
.container-fluid {
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-right:0px
}
```